# prisma-select issue for custom output path

Tags: microservices, nestjs, prisma, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am getting the below error when I try to use

`const select = new PrismaSelect(info).value;`

> [Nest] 65877   - 17/05/2021, 16:45:13   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot find module '.prisma/client'

My PrismaClient is in a custom path rather than the default, as I am using a monorepo for multiple microservices.

```
generator client {
    provider      = "prisma-client-js"
    binaryTargets = ["native", "darwin"]
    output        = "../src/.generated/prisma/client"
}
```

Is there a way to point PrismaSelect to the correct Client?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was shared by the author of the package

Import custom instance of Prisma Client

```
import { Prisma } from '../../.generated/prisma/client';
```

Pass dmmf object to PrismaSelect constructor

```
const select = new PrismaSelect(info, { dmmf: [Prisma.dmmf] }).value;
```